# You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype int32

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

The following code gives me the error:

> You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype int32

Why do I get this error? I am using Python 3 with Google colab GPU.

```py
    import tensorflow as tf  

    d1 = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
    d2 = tf.add(6, 2, name="Add_these_numbers2")
    d3 = tf.add(d1, d2, name="res5")
    d4 = tf.add(d1, d3, name="res5")

    with tf.Session() as sess:
       # writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("output", sessi.graph)
        print(sess.run(d3))
        print(sess.run(d4,feed_dict={d1:0}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not feeding `d1` during `sess.run(d3)` (i.e. `d3` is dependent on `d1`).

Following works.

```
import tensorflow as tf  

d1 = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
d2 = tf.add(6, 2, name="Add_these_numbers2")
d3 = tf.add(d1, d2, name="res5")
d4 = tf.add(d1, d3, name="res5")

with tf.Session() as sess:
   # writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("output", sessi.graph)
    print(sess.run(d3, feed_dict={d1:0}))
    print(sess.run(d4, feed_dict={d1:0}))
```